# Creating nested variables for a nested ANOVA in R

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a nested ANOVA in R. I am looking at the effect of 4 different cytokine containing media crossed with (or without) valproic acid. So this makes a 4x2 factorial design to be analysed in 2-way ANOVA.

I have done that part fine, but the problem I am encountering is to do with nesting. The data I have obtained is from pictures from a number of sites, which are nested within plates, which are nested within subject. ie each data value is from 1 of 4 sites from 1 of 2 plates from 1 of 3 subjects which is categorised by the media and VPA levels. ie 4 sites x 2 plates x 2 VPA levels x 4 media levels = 64 observations per subject. Is this right?

If it is... I wish to perform a nested ANOVA (aSMA is the outcome/response/dependent variable):

```
aov(aSMA~factor(Site%in%Plate%in%Media)*factor(Site%in%Plate%in%VPA))
```

I have tried this type of format in R but it gives me an error in contrasts message claiming that at least one of these has only one level. However, these all have at least one level.

HELP!!! 
Please and thank you

Comment: if u can provide any reproducible example with data it will be useful.. your question is very confusing

Comment: Sorry, so I'm not sure how to explain it other than this... I have two crossed factors (media and VPA) and two nested ones (plate and site). How can I perform a nested ANOVA on these data? I presume you need to specify that the the error terms contain the nested factors. I can give you the whole data if that would help to understand it.